# A csv file appears empty while it is not

Tags: python, csv

I'm creating a program that will write information from a vote into a new file for results, and I need to check if the file is empty before writing in all the available voting options. (Otherwise the data would overwrite the already entered in results each time a person voted). My problem is, it's not returning anything when I run the piece of code. Here it is:

```
def VOTE1():
        Data = ("VOTE")
        voteChoice = OptionAmount.get()
        with open('EXISTINGVOTE.CSV') as infile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
            for row in reader:
                if voteChoice == row['TITLE NAME']:
                    f = open('{}.csv'.format(row['TITLE NAME']), "w")
                    f.close()
                    with open('{}.csv'.format(row['TITLE NAME']), "r") as f:
                        VoteRead = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
                        for row in VoteRead:
                            for field in row:
                                if field == Data:
                                    print("Empty file")
                                else:
                                    print("There is data in here")
                else:
                    print("Not this one")
```

I should be getting a statement saying "Empty file" or "There is data in here"

Comment: What are you getting instead? `"Not this one"` or nothing at all?

Comment: @lucasnadalutti I'm getting nothing at all

Comment: How about reading [ask] and [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you destroy the file contents by opening the file for writing …

```
f = open('{}.csv'.format(row['TITLE NAME']), "w")
```

… and then you read the now empty new file.

```
open('{}.csv'.format(row['TITLE NAME']), "r") as f
```

What you probably want to do is to open the file to append data:

```
if voteChoice == row['TITLE NAME']:
    # two lines deleted
    with open('{}.csv'.format(row['TITLE NAME']), "a") as f:
```

Comment: I made the changes but now it's giving me   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\New stuff\VoteMenu2.py", line 191, in VOTE1
    for row in VoteRead:
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: That's the error I got when I changed the code to that.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev searching it up I found that opening it as 'a' was giving it problems so I changed it to "wb" but now I get the error: io.UnsupportedOperation: read rather than the not readable error

Comment: Anyway, that's an error unrelated to the problem this question deals with.

Comment: Don’t you want to read from infile and append the data to f? Why do you try to read from f, then?

Comment: after fixing the problem it's taken me back to my original issue. Nothing prints once the function is ran and @Marvo I changed it to read, and that's what fixed that issue